# What does 'Analysis Model Value' in NASTRAN optimization mean?

Tags: structural-analysis, structures, aerospace-engineering

I am new to MSC NASTRAN and PATRAN.
I am running a simulation on composite laminate optimization. While creating the design variables for the study, I noticed that there is a parameter called 'Analysis Model Value'. I am unable to understand the physical significance of this term. I searched the documentation provided by MSC but I am still unable to come up with a solution.